# Divide $n > 10$ distinct elements $\{1,2, \dots, n\}$ to $3$ distinct sets $A,B,C$ where $|A|=5$ and $|B|>|C|$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to use the inclusion-exclusion principle here but having a problem calculating the cases.

Assume $D_1$ - the possible ways to choose a number not equal to $5$ members for $A$

and $D_2$ - the possible ways to divide the elements where $|B| \leq |A|$

and $U$ - all possible divisions of $n$ elements to $A,B,C$

And I want to calculate $\bar{D_1} \cap \bar{D_2}=|U| - |D_1|-|D_2|+|D_1 \cap D_2|$

Now, $|U|$ is the number of functions from a set of the cardinality of $n$ to a set of the cardinality of $3$ which given $|U|=3^n$

But the other calculations seem too confusing. Should we solve it this way? how to calculate the rest of the expression if so? or how to solve it in a better way?

Comment: I dont think PIE is needed,the number of ways is $$\sum_{k>n/2}^{n-5} \binom{n}{5}\binom{n-5}{k}$$

Comment: Nice, and I think this can even be turned into an expression without the Sigma sign. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a greatly simplified inclusion-exclusion idea.

Once you have chosen the 5 elements for set A you must split the remaining $n-5$ elements into two sets. When you do this you either have or do not have two sets of equal size.

**If $n-5$ is odd**

The sets have to be unequal in size and so half the possibilities have B larger than C. The number of possibilities is $2^{n-6}\binom{n}{5}$.

**If $n-5=2k$ is even**

We have to **exclude** the cases when the sets are equal. The number of possibilities is $\frac{1}{2}(2^{n-5}-\binom{n-5}{k})\binom{n}{5}$.